# executing async method in onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerView` which items of `recyclerView` has a `textView` sometimes with links in it. I use [richLinkPreview](https://github.com/PonnamKarthik/RichLinkPreview) for previewing my link inside each item has a link. But when I scroll the `recyclerView` I face a problem that is every time I view an item with link, it goes to bring link data and show it and sometimes it shows wrong link preview(shows link preview of item A in item B). I think my problem is calling `richLinkPreview` inside `onBindViewHolder` method but I have not any option in my knowledge. Could you help me with that?

Comment: You could try checking each `ViewHolder`'s id before actually updating the UI.
In `onBindViewHolder`, you get passed a `position` and a `ViewHolder`. You could, before updating the UI, check if that position and `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final SparseArray<MetaData> mFetchedMetadata = new SparseArray<>();

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final @NonNull Adapter.ViewHolder holder,
                                 final int position) {

        ...
        final MetaData metadata = mFetchedMetadata.get(position);
        if (metadata != null) {
            holder.richLinkView.setLinkFromMeta(metadata);
        } else {
            holder.richLinkView.setLink("url", new ViewListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(boolean status) {
                    mFetchedMetadata.put(position, holder.richLinkView.getMetaData());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                }
            });
        }
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```